How can I make sure this is a secure LDAP connection and write AD's unicodePwd attribute?
I'm using a Vagrant VM with Ubuntu 24.04 Noble to develop a project. I'm using Node 20.18.0 and NestJs 10.4.5.
In one of the routes, I´m trying to access a secure ldap server using NodeJs's ldapts library. The objective of connecting securely is to write the unicodePwd field in the AD.
Microsoft has this documentation relative to writing unicodePwd attribute. Basically the password has to be enclosed in double quotes and it must be UTF-16 encoded. Then the attribute should be written in a secure connection.
Inititally I tried connection this way:
const client = new Client({
    url: 'ldaps://<ldapip>',
    timeout: 0,
    connectTimeout: 0,
});
const bindDN = 'CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=myproject,DC=local';
const password = 'mypdw';

try {
    console.log('D1');
    let cert = fs.readFileSync('/vagrant/backend/certs/mycert.crt');

    console.log(cert.toString('base64'));
    await client.startTLS({
      ca: [cert],
    });
    
    console.log('D2');
    await client.bind(bindDN, password);
    
    console.log('D3');
    (...)
} catch (error) {
    return { status: 500, msg: 'LDAP fail', error }
} finally {
    await client.unbind();
}

When I run this code, D0, D1 and the certificate are printed correctly, but it doesn't reach point D2. It was failing with the following error:
{"code":"UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"}}

I know for sure that the certificate is emmited by the AD's CA. I'm using Chromium and the CA is correctly imported to it.
I also tried to create a file with both the user certificate and the CA's certificate in it and it didn't work also.
Then I've done some changes to the code and now it connects, but I'm not sure I have a secure connection in place because I can't do what I need to do with it (writing unicodePwd attribute). Is there a way to check if the secure connection is in place ? or just connecting and binding to ldaps://myserver:636 is enough to guarantee a secure connection ?
This is the current version of the code:
// I tried the line below both with ca and client certs with equal results
let cert = fs.readFileSync('/vagrant/backend/certs/client-cert.crt');
let opts = {
    ca: [cert],
    host: 'myurl.myproject.local',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    secure: true         
};  
const client = new Client({
    url: 'ldaps://myurl.myproject.local:636',
    timeout: 0,
    tlsOptions: {
        ...opts, 
        minVersion: 'TLSv1.1'
    },
    connectTimeout: 0,
});
const bindDN = 'CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=myproject,DC=local';
const password = 'mypdw';
    
try {
    console.log('D1');
    console.log(cert.toString('base64'));
        
    console.log('D2');
    await client.bind(bindDN, password);
        
    console.log('D3', client.isConnected);
        
    let passwdUtf16 = this.encodePassword("mypwd");
        
    var newUser = {
        sn: 'teste',
        objectClass: ["organizationalPerson", "person", "user"],
        unicodePwd: passwdUtf16
    }       

    await client.add('cn=test,ou=MyCompany,ou=Organizations,dc=myproject,dc=local', newUser);
        
    console.log('D4');

I also tried to add the user without the unicodePwd attribute (it works) and then do this:
let change = new Change({ operation: 'replace', modification: new Attribute({ type: 'unicodePwd;binary', values: [passwdUtf16] }) });

await client.modify('cn=test,ou=MyCompany,ou=Organizations,dc=myproject,dc=local', change);

In both cases I'm getting the UnwillingToPerformError leading me to think I don't have a secure connection in place.
This is the encodePassword function:
encodePassword(str) {
  const text = '"' + str + '"';
  let byteArray = new Uint8Array(text.length * 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    byteArray[i * 2] = text.charCodeAt(i); // & 0xff;
    byteArray[i * 2 + 1] = text.charCodeAt(i) >> 8; // & 0xff;
  }
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, byteArray);
}

Now I have to questions:

How can I assert this is a secure connection in order to write unicodePwd attribute correctly ?

Am I doing anything wrong writing the password ?



Is mycert self-signed by your organization? If yes, nodejs doesn't trust it by default, even if it's in the machine's keystore. You could for instance use this to fix this

Yes it's self signed. I did many things to try to connect. Among them what's written in that answer. See my edit.

Generally please don't turn a SO thread into a completely different topic – if you've solved the initial problem, post an answer to show everyone how you solved it, then open a separate question about the password change.

@grawity_u1686 I'lll rewrite the whole thing as I don't want to loose the bounty time.

@grawity_u1686 see if you think it's better. I didn't want to put an answer to the initial question because although the first error didn't apear anymore I'm not sure to have fixed it correctly as I'm not sure I really have a secure connection.

I was finally able to write AD's password in NodeJs/NestJs. The answer was simpler than I thought.
To answer my own questions:

How can I assert this is a secure connection in order to write unicodePwd attribute correctly ?

There's no need to use startTLS function. Just binding to a client directed to ldaps:// is enough. You can check if the connection is using a secure TLS encoding using Wireshark. Just point to the network interface and it will clearly state that it's using TLS.

Am I doing anything wrong writing the password ?

At least on our test lab AD, there's no need to set dsHeuristics field as stated by @ErkinD39. You can just use a replace change in the modify function for unicodePwd field. Just make sure of 3 things:

the password string should be surrounded by double quotes
Should be utf-16 encoded and
there's no password rules policy in place.

In our case the only thing blocking the password write and generating UnwillingToPerform error was that the password we were using for tests didn't follow password rules. As soon as we tried a password that included alphas, numbers and a special char it worked. We used user@123 as password.
Here's the complete working code:
let certCA = fs.readFileSync('/vagrant/backend/certs/cacert.crt');
const client = new Client({
    url: 'ldaps://myurl.myproject.local',
    tlsOptions: {
        ca: [certCA],
    }
});
const bindDN = 'CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=myproject,DC=local';
const password = 'adm@123';

try {
    await client.bind(bindDN, password);

    let pwd = "user@123";
    let passwdUtf16 =  Buffer.from(`"${pwd}"`, 'utf16le'); 
    let newUser = {
        sn: 'test',
        objectClass: ["organizationalPerson", "person", "user"],
    }

    await client.add('cn=test,ou=Company,ou=Organizations,dc=myproject,dc=local', newUser);

    let changeReplPwd = new Change({ operation: 'replace', modification: new Attribute({ type: 'unicodePwd', values: [passwdUtf16] })}) ;
        
    await client.modify('cn=test,ou=Company,ou=Organizations,dc=myproject,dc=local', [changeReplPwd]);

} catch (error) {
    return { status: 500, msg: 'LDAP fail', error }
} finally {
    await client.unbind();
}

you can also include the user with password directly this way:
let certCA = fs.readFileSync('/vagrant/backend/certs/cacert.crt');
const client = new Client({
    url: 'ldaps://myurl.myproject.local',
    tlsOptions: {
        ca: [certCA]
    }
});
const bindDN = 'CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=myproject,DC=local';
const password = 'adm@123';

try {
    await client.bind(bindDN, password);
    
    let pwd = "user@123";
    // please note the line below is different from the example above      
    let passwdUtf16 =  String.fromCharCode.apply(String, Buffer.from(`"${pwd}"`, 'utf16le')); 
    
    var newUser = {
        sn: 'test',
        objectClass: ["organizationalPerson", "person", "user"],
        unicodePwd: passwdUtf16
    }

    await client.add('cn=test,ou=Company,ou=Organizations,dc=myproject,dc=local', newUser);

} catch (error) {
    return { status: 500, msg: 'LDAP fail', error }
} finally {
    await client.unbind();
}



As per the following statement SASL-layer encryption is also accepted instead of SSL/TLS.

"On Windows Server 2003 operating system and later, the DC also permits modification of the unicodePwd attribute on a connection protected by 128-bit (or better) Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL)-layer encryption instead of SSL/TLS."
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2
I think special to this attribute the document says:
"For the password change operation to succeed, the server enforces the requirement that the user or inetOrgPerson object whose password is being changed MUST possess the "User-Change-Password" control access right on itself, and that Vdel MUST be the current password on the object."
You may increase LDAP logging level following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/configure-ad-and-lds-event-logging. Diagnostics subkey referenced in the article may be chosen as 16 or 27 to check LDAP interface events or PDC password update notifications respectively. Logging level may be chosen as 4 (verbose).

How can I set User-Change-Password control access right progamatically when adding users on Node ? Vdel ? you mean a string with those chars ? What's Vdel ?

I think vDel stands for the old password variable. If the functions you use does an administrative reset password without knowing the old password, the vDel is not needed. I tested with Ldp.exe that if you bind with a DN and password, LDAP Simple Bind is chosen automatically, and I could not bind with this method On LDAPs (port 636). This probably is the reason you can not connect with both TLS and simple bind. Is it possible to choose another authentication method?  ldp.exe connection reveals supported methods (digest, GSSAPI etc)

I have regenerated the the issue with ldp.exe and tried to modify userPassword and unicodePwd attributes with 'unwilling to perform' error. Then I have set dsHeuristics to 000000001 which sets the fUserPwdSupport to 1, therefore userPassword (and I assume also unicodePwd) updateable via LDAP(S). Then I was able to modify both fields. There is one hint I have found from posts is writing the unicodePwd value in \UNI:"pwdhere" format (https://serverfault.com/questions/17217/how-do-you-reset-a-password-in-ad-using-ldp-exe). Then AD was willing to update unicodePwd :) . I hope this helps.
